# Intuitive proof of the formula ${}_nC_r + {}_nC_{r-1} = {}_{n+1}C_r$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I came across this formula in combination— ${}_nC_r + {}_nC_{r-1} = {}_{n+1}C_r$. Even though I know its rigorous mathematical proof, I want a logical and elegant proof of this.

For example, the famous formula of combination ${}_nC_r = {}_nC_{n-r}$ says selecting $r$ objects out of $n$ objects is same as rejecting $(n-r)$ objects.

So, I am looking for such kind of intuitive proof of the formula ${}_nC_r + {}_nC_{r-1} = {}_{n+1}C_r$, which I am unable to get.

The thought of the wise man who said "writing a correct equation but not being able to interpret its result is the same as writing a grammatically correct sentence without knowing what it means!!!" is not helping me either!!
Note— ${}_nC_r$ means combination of $n$ objects taken $r$ at a time.

Comment: Are you looking for a proof of the statement $\binom{n}{r} + \binom{n}{r - 1} = \binom{n + 1}{r}$, a proof of the statement $\binom{n}{r} = \binom{n}{n - r}$, or both statements?

Comment: The right side counts words of $r$ As and $n+1-r$ Bs.  The first term on the left, ${}_nC_r$, counts words of $r$ As and $n+1-r$ Bs that start with a B. The second term on the left, ${}_nC_{r-1}$, counts words of $r$ As and $n+r-1$ Bs that start with an A.

Comment: @taussig please read the question properly before commenting I think that I stressed upon the fact that I know the mathematical proof of the equation but want a logical/intuitive proof of the equation something like the one I gave for - (n)(c)(r)=(n)(c)(n-r)  of selecting r thing's out of n ....and all that given in question.

Comment: @will ... Will you please explain the comment a bit more because I am not able to understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: The number of ways of arranging the letters AAABB is $\frac{5!}{3!\,2!}={}_5C_3={}_5C_2=10$.  This can be understood as a selection process: there are $5$ letter positions; you have to choose where to put the As (alternatively the Bs).  In general, ${}_nC_r$ counts arrangements of the "word" with $r$ As and $n-r$ Bs.  My comment interprets both sides of the equation in terms of word arrangements.

Comment: I think some misconceptions have occurred edited the question please look at it

Comment: That is I want an intuitive explanation of the first equation

Comment: I stated the second equation to explain that I was looking for an explanation like the one you gave here for the first equation

Comment: To illustrate my comment by an example: ${}_5C_3={}_4C_2+{}_4C_3$, which holds since $10=6+4$.  What is the interpretation of the numbers $10$, $6$, and $4$?  The set of five-letter words of three As is {AAABB, AABAB, AABBA, ABAAB, ABABA, ABBAA, BAAAB, BAABA, BABAA, BBAAA}.  This can be split into subsets of sizes $6$ and $4$ according to whether the first letter is A or B.  If the first letter is A, the rest of the word is a four-letter word with two As; if the first letter is B, the rest of the word is a four-letter word with three As.  I don't know if this gives the intuition you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a combinatorial proof of Pascal's Identity
$$\binom{n + 1}{r} = \binom{n}{r} + \binom{n}{r - 1}$$
where $$\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n - r)!}$$ is the number of ways of making an unordered selection of $r$ elements from a set of $n$ elements.

We can select $r \geq 1$ elements from the set $$S_{n + 1} = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n, x_{n + 1}\}$$ in $\binom{n + 1}{r}$ ways.  Such selections either include $x_{n + 1}$ or they do not.  If a selection of $r$ elements includes $x_{n + 1}$, we must select $r - 1$ elements from the subset $$S_n  = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$$ and $x_{n + 1}$.  We can select $r - 1$ elements from the subset $S_n$ in $\binom{n}{r - 1}$ ways and select $x_{n + 1}$ in one way.  If the selection does not include $x_{n + 1}$, we must select $r$ elements from $S_n$, which can be done in $\binom{n}{r}$ ways.  Hence, the number of ways of selecting $r$ elements from a set of $n + 1$ elements is 
$$\binom{n + 1}{r} = \binom{n}{r - 1}\binom{1}{1} + \binom{n}{r} = \binom{n}{r - 1} + \binom{n}{r}$$

Comment: $\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n - r)!} = C(n, r)$.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: But there is just one doubt.. $$x(1),x(2),x(3)...$$ are the elements of the set with which we are dealing with...and from which we are required to select or order things ..right??

Comment: The numbers $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n, x_{n + 1}$ are elements of the set from which we are selecting $r$ elements.  The set is not ordered.  We are counting the number of ways we can select $r$ elements in two ways.  The number $\binom{n + 1}{r}$ represents the total number of ways we can select $r$ elements from a set of $n + 1$ elements.  We can also count the number of selections that either include a particular element of the set (which I called $x_{n + 1}$), of which there are $\binom{n}{r - 1}$, or do not include it, of which there are $\binom{n}{r}$.

Comment: OK...so let me just take an example...as example obviously always help...so lets say I take 10 boxes named..$A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J$ (that is $n=10$)...and say..I want to select 6 boxes( that is $r=6$) now I have got in your answers terms(IN terms of sets $S_n$ and $S_n+1$) $$S_n  = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{10}\}$$ or $={A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J}$...but..

Comment: But ..how are you going to write the set $S_n+1$..how will you take the $11th$ element..as you have written..$$ S_{n + 1} = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n, x_{n + 1}\}$$...but how can you ..if only 10 elements $A,B,C...J$ were originally given to us..moreover you have also talked of the x(n+1)th element..but say in this situation...how can we take or talk about the 11th box..as only 10 were there...

Comment: Let $S_{n + 1} = \{A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K\} = S_n \cup \{K\}$.  We wish to make selections of six boxes from $S_{n + 1}$.  We either take six boxes from $S_n$ or we take five boxes from $S_n$ and we take box $K$.

Comment: Do you mean in second last line ... ***we either take six boxes from $s_{n+1}$..***

Comment: No.  In order to take six boxes from $S_{n + 1}$, which, given that $n = 10$ in this case, we can do in $\binom{11}{6}$ ways, we can either take six boxes from $S_n$, which we can do in $\binom{10}{6}$ ways, or we can take five boxes from $S_n$, which we can do in $\binom{10}{5}$ ways, and take box $K$, which we can do in $\binom{1}{1}$ ways.  Hence, $\binom{11}{6} = \binom{10}{6} + \binom{10}{5}\binom{1}{1} = \binom{10}{6} + \binom{10}{5}$.

Comment: 5th line spelling correction: "numbered" should be "number".

Comment: @MrAP  Thank you for alerting me to the error.  Corrected.

Answer (score 6):

Assume the $n+1$ objects are balls, with only one of them being red and the rest white.

A particular selection of $r$ balls has to either contain the red ball or not.

Those selections omitting the red ball are $^{n}C_r$. Those selections containing the red ball have choice in which $r-1$ white balls have to be chosen, and this is given by $^{n}C_{r-1}$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it a bit more

Comment: You are implicitly assuming that the $n$ white balls are distinguishable.  Making that assumption explicit would complete your proof.